# get all category names of articles in index function many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm trying to get only the category names, of all articles on the `index()` function on Laravel. So all articles and the related categories of each article. It's a many-to-many relationship.

What i did so far:

```
  foreach($articles as $article) {
            if (isset($article)) {
                $article['categories'] = $article->category;
            }
        }
```

This gets me all articles with the related categories as a collection, it works, but not quite what I want. As I said, I want only the category names.

I tried `$article->category->name;` obviously did not work
also: `$article->category->get('name');`

furthermore what is interesting, If I rename `$article['categories']` to  `$article['cat']` I get 2 collections the category with all related category objects and another exact same on just names cat.

I also tried:

```
...
$article['categories'] = $this->getcat($articles);
return response()->json($articles, 200);
}

public function getcat($query) {
  if (isset($query) && is_countable($query)) {
            foreach ($query as &$entity) {
                if (!isset($entity)) { continue; }

                if (isset($entity->categories)) {
                    $originObjects = $entity->categories;
                    $competition_all = [];
                    foreach($originObjects as $object) {
                        array_push($competition_all, $object->name);
                    }
                    return $competition_all;
                }
            }
        }
```

The function returns what I need, but it does not return it as json, on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see.. your response is return `response()->json($names, 200);` , but your categories names array is saved into the `$article['categories']` array. So.. if you return the `response()->json($article, 200);`, your categories names should be returned as json. The reason that `$article->category->name;` does not works is because this is array with objects because the type of your relation, but here you call only property.

The better way is to add to the query, the with function and pass the relation as first parameter, and then in second to add anonym function with the query and select only the names.

Eg.

```
$articles = Article::with('category', function($q) { ... })->get();
```